# Sony Xperia X Rooting issue when the unlock bootloader flag is set to no

Tags: root-access, sony-xperia, bootloader-lock

I am trying to unlock a Sony Xperia X that was locked to a Canadian carrier (Freedom). The previous owner sold me the phone unlocked (SIM) but he failed to unlock the bootloader.

I followed the instructions [here](https://developer.sony.com/develop/open-devices/get-started/unlock-bootloader/how-to-unlock-bootloader/) and realized that the rooting status states that `boot-locker unlock is set to no`.

I also got the developer options enabled and made sure that the OEM unlocking is set to true and USB debugging set to true.

Next I ran adb devices and my device shows up.

[image]

However I ran fast-boot devices after starting the phone in bootloader mode (<kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + insert USB cable), it doesn't recognize any device.

I am wondering: is there any way I can get around Sony's restrictive Boot-loader unlock setting and get root on my phone? I desperately need to get rid of some bloatware.

Comment: Have you installed the fastboot drivers? Windows requires different drivers for ADB and fastboot mode. Boot to bootloader connect the device and check the device manager for unknown devices.

Comment: So this is what I did, after connecting my phone and firing up a CMD window ,I looked for fastboot devices and it showed nothing. Out of curiosity I rebooted into bootloader using fastboot command ( think it was fastboot reboot bootloader ) and it booted my phone in the bootloader mode. This should confirm that I have the right fastboot drivers installed right ?

Comment: The only real confirmation that fastboot drivers are working correctly is that `fastboot devices` lists your device. Boot to bootloader and search for `Android Bootloader interface` or something like this. See also: http://www.wtfandroid.com/fix-fastboot-device-not-recognised-problem/

Comment: @Robert Thank you. i will give this a shot when i get home. i wouldn't be surprised if the fastboot drivers are not installed properly